# How to get forecast using `stlf()` in R

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am new to **R**. I am using the `stlf()` function in the **forecast** package to forecast trends in air passengers using the following code:

```
fit <- stlf(AirPassengers, lambda=BoxCox.lambda(AirPassengers))
```

My questions:

1. Does the point forecast given by this method correspond to the input data or is it a future forecast?
2. How can I specify the number of forecast periods?

Comment: Why don't you try reading the help file, or the associated book at http://www.otexts.org/fpp/6/6

Comment: I tried..But still have confusion. I wan to know is `stlf()` gives me forecast corresponding to the input observations?

Comment: 1. Look at `fit` and `AirPassengers`. 2. Look at `?stlf` and search for an argument that looks like "number of periods for forecasting". It may help that the *forecast horizon* is often abbreviated *h*.